# Can I use the same 240 circuit for hot tub and sauna outdoors?

Tags: wiring

I am purchasing an outdoor sauna that will be 240VAC and max draw of 18.5 amps.
I have an existing hot tub wired to a 50A breaker that will be next to it. It draws less than 30A.
Can I split the wiring and hardwire the same circuit to the sauna? Do I need more breakers?

Comment: I would want to see the manufacturer listing. If it only draws 18.5 it really should not be on a 50A but a 30A there is an allowance for motors to use larger breakers for starting but most mfg’s identify the minimum conductor size and maximum breaker.  If it only draws 19A 150% or next size up was the limit (unless motor requires). I have posted the code ref in the past but would need to look it up again.

Comment: @EdBeal  The sauna he's going to purchase draws 18.5 amps.  His existing  hot tub draws less than 30 amp so that could very well be a 50 amp breaker.

Comment: @JACK You can't put 18.5A of continuous load on a 20A circuit though, need the 125% derate which pushes you into a 25A circuit.  And you must obey labeling and instructions, because the appliance is designed to rely on those protective devices, that's how UL approved it.

Comment: @jack as I said I would need to see the mfg name plate some devices are limited to 150% the maximum. inverse time breaker is 250% Fla for a motor table 430.52 but this is a complete system at 18.5 so I rounded up to 19. you don’t just say if the breaker is bigger it’s ok, I would not be surprised and actually expect the mfg has a max of 30a on a dedicated GFCI circuit.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine  I wasn't considering the sauna as continuous load since it was on a timer/shutoff switch.

Comment: @EdBeal  Hi Ed.  I didn't think this was continuous load. Inspectors give some leeway on that. Many saunas don't have motors so that was my reasoning for the 20 amp breaker. You're right about it probably being higher which is why I mentioned the manufacturer's specifications. Good to see you back more.

Comment: It is considered fixed heating I am not saying that they both could not be on a 50 amp feeder but they require individual breakers in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Each one should have it's own breaker. You can install a sub panel fed from the existing hot tub wires. From the sub panel, run a 30 amp breaker run to the sauna  and a 30 amp breaker run to the hot tub. Breaker sizes could be different depending on what the manufacturers specify.